# Inserting in a table from a two table join using Trigger for filter

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am working on oracle DB, and having for exemple this two tables :

```
TABLE A :
ID     Phone   WEEK    MODEL
 1     10      14-18   XYX
 2     32      15-18   XXZ
 3     40      15-18   XYX
 4     19      16-18   ZZT
 5     10      14-18   XYX

 TABLE B :

 ID   MODEL    TRAFIC
  1   XYX      2G/3G
  2   XCA      2G/3G/4G
  3   ZZT      2G/3G/4G
  4   ABC      2G only
  5   XYZ      2G/3G
  6   XXZ      2G only


  TABLE C RESULTS of JOIN :

  ID   Phone   WEEK    MODEL   TRAFIC
 1     10      14-18   XYX     2G/3G
 2     32      15-18   XXZ     2G only
 3     40      15-18   XYX     2G/3G
 4     19      16-18   ZZT     2G/3G/4G
```

Now, I want to insert the rows in table B and the Table A (JOIN) , into Table C `where (A.Phone != C.Phone and A.WEEK != C.WEEK)`

Here's the sql script for the insert, in the first place the result table C, is empty :

```
INSERT INTO C(PHONE, MODEL, TRAFIC, WEEK)
SELECT DISTINCT PHONE, WEEK, MODEL,TRAFIC
        FROM(SELECT WEEK, A.PHONE,A.MODEL,B.TRAFIC
            FROM A
            LEFT JOIN B ON B.model = A.model)
GROUP BY PHONE, WEEK;
```

I want to use a trigger while inserting the values, it will first check if the phone has already been inserted in the same week
  Thanks.

Comment: Looks very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165403/trigger-to-prevent-inserting-rows-with-filter)

Comment: @Aleksej It's maybe because of the same tutorial exercice, that we re using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code, without using the trigger, but comparing the existence of data combinations:

```
INSERT INTO C(PHONE, MODEL, TRAFIC, WEEK)
SELECT DISTINCT PHONE, WEEK, MODEL,TRAFIC
  FROM (SELECT A.WEEK, A.PHONE,A.MODEL,B.TRAFIC
          FROM A
          LEFT JOIN B ON B.model = A.model
         WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                             FROM C
                            WHERE C.PHONE = A.PHONE
                              AND C.WEEK = A.WEEK))
GROUP BY PHONE, WEEK;
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to prevent the insert inside the trigger. If you really need to use the trigger, alternative can be to make an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` that would delete all rows from `C` table that were just inserted but shouldn't have been (using another table to store rows that will need to be deleted).

Example I found for that alternative can be found here:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/484449?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: I will try this, in the same time, is there a way that I can use a trigger ? because am doing an exercice from a tutorial that forces you to do a trigger

Comment: @ImadELa  I edited my answer with further info on trigger use.

Comment: And can you please show me how to delete after inserting using this logic ?

Comment: @ImadELa I would disapprove with using trigger in this instance since there is no need for it and it requires additional objects in DB. To add to that, it can be simply avoided with changing your code to the one I posted in my answer. If you nevertheless still want to use a trigger, you can reference the link I posted above and contact me if you get some error(s).